# Teensy with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, udev, arduino

I'm trying to get my teensy board to work with ubuntu. I've copied the udev rules they provide:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="04[789]?", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="04[789]?", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}="1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="04[789]?", MODE:="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="04[789]?", MODE:="0666"
```

But, nothing is appearing under /dev/ttyACM* after reloading the rules, or unplugging/plugging back in.

I can see it on lsusb:

```
$lsusb
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 16c0:0486 Van Ooijen Technische Informatica Teensyduino RawHID
```

running udevadm test results in:

```
$ udevadm test /dev/bus/003/015
calling: test
version 204
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          204
file size:         5774243 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1271747 bytes
nodes              4502416 bytes
load module index
...
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/49-teensy.rules
....
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 33780 bytes strings
21462 strings (183267 bytes), 18149 de-duplicated (152801 bytes), 3314 trie nodes used
unable to open device '/sys/dev/bus/003/015'
unload module index
```

I'm going to assume that the that the 'unable to open device' error is irrelevant, since that shows up on my arduino board as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Teensy uses something called Raw HID, it will not show up as a serial port. To be able to program it, their add-on to arduino needs to be installed:

https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_download.html